# How to reduce space above and below minted?

Tags: spacing, minted, vertical

I'm using `minted` to display some code in my document and I noticed an uncomfortably large space above and below the `minted` environment and I wasn't able to find out where does the space come from, and how to reduce it.

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
% \setminted{bgcolor=lightgray}
\begin{document}
\loggingoutput
Hello
\begin{minted}{latex}
  \spaced
\end{minted}
world!
\end{document}
```

I also noticed that when I add the `bgcolor` option, the spacing around the code block increases slightly, which I thought that was due to an extra spacing for the frame.

What I did notice is that if I add `\loggingoutput` the logs are very different with and without the backgound color. Without the `bgcolor` option, between the `Hello` line and the code there is this:

```
...\penalty -51
...\glue 8.0 plus 3.0 minus 4.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.05556
```

so considering that I can't change the `\baselineskip` of the document, I think I would need to reduce that `\glue 8.0 plus 3.0 minus 4.0`.

However I *do* want the `bgcolor`. Activating that option, the output of `\loggingoutput` between the `Hello` line and the code block is the slightly more convoluted:

```
...\glue 6.0 plus 2.0 minus 2.0
...\glue 0.0
...\penalty 9999
...\penalty -30
...\penalty 0
...\glue 0.0 plus 7.38602
...\penalty 1800
...\glue 0.0 plus -7.38602
...\glue 0.0
...\penalty 10000
...\glue 24.0
...\glue 6.0
...\penalty 9999
...\glue -24.0
...\glue -6.0
...\penalty 9999
...\glue(\baselineskip) 6.0
...\vbox(6.0+0.0)x0.0
...\penalty 10000
...\glue -6.0
...\penalty 10000
```

although the space doesn't change much.

So, to the question(s):

- How do I reduce the space above and below the `minted` environment (with and without the `bgcolor` option)?
- Why does the logged output is so different with and without `bgcolor`?

Comment: It looks like lines 6--8 of the log output tell TeX that that is a bad page break (`\penalty 1800`). The spaces before and after that penalty node cancel out, so if the page break doesn't happen there, the output isn't affected. The same goes for lines 11--15 and 18--20 (a `\vbox` 6 pt high with a negative space of 6 pt. Remove those, some `\glue 0.0`, and penalties and you are left with `...\glue 6.0 plus 2.0 minus 2.0 ...\glue(\baselineskip) 6.0`, which isn't too different from the other case. I might be wrong, though...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Sorry, I don't completely understand what those things mean, only the basics. But what you said makes sense, the  `\glue`s cancel out, except for the `\penalties` between them. Do you know how do I reduce the space then?

Comment: The penalties tell TeX how bad it is to break the page in a certain place. If the page break doesn't happen there, then the penalty "disappears" and the glues cancel out. Sorry, I don't how to change that spacing. You could change the `\baselineskip` inside the `minted` environment though...