# Unwanted spacing: How to cancel out `.....\glue(\xx) xx.xx` found in .log file?

Tags: vertical-spacing, logging, glue

I'm trying to figure out why vertical space is added between elements in my document. I am using `\loggingoutput` which i learned about in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509228/how-to-reduce-space-above-and-below-minted) to get a verbose log from TeX. Many lines look like this:

```
.....\glue 10.0
.....\glue(\baselineskip) 4.35005
```

I would like to negate the vertical space introduced at `\glue(\baselineskip) 4.35005`, but the number seems to change depending on where I place things in my document. What do the parentheses mean? Is this value computed from `\baselineskip`?

Comment: First, see if `\raggedbottom` fixes your problem.  If not, try `\setlength{\baselineskip}{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}`.

Comment: The value in the log changes, but it doesn't seem to solve anything... how is that supposed to work?

Comment: the value is computed, it is the amount needed to get the distance between the baselines of the two lines to be \baselineskip.

Comment: Thank you, that is good to know. Could there by any chance be a way to find out which command is causing it? Or could there be a way to cancel out this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculation of the `\baselineskip` glue depends on context. In the vertical direction, TeX tries to maintain a constant baseline-to-baseline distance. For example (I am simplifying a lot here), consider

```
... properties... this line has a descending letter p
... this line has ascending letters h, l, and d...

versus

... no descenders on this line...
... nooooooooooooooooooooooooo...
```

If you want constant baseline-to-baseline distance, then: between the first two lines, the gap must be smaller; between the last two lines, the gap must be larger.

To turn off this calculation (locally and for only once), you can issue `\nointerlineskip`, like this:

```
... previous paragraph.


\nointerlineskip
<your object>


Next paragraph...
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!